# Input loses focus when typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem using inputs... I've got two inputs: one has autofocus and the other doesn't. However, when I type in the second input, it loses focus andthe focus returns to the first input.

I've read that React rerenders my component when I type something. I tried putting a key prop and etc, but nothing worked.

In my form (a component called Signup), I have the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import Input from '../../components/Input'
import styles from './styles.scss'

class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
    }
  }

  onSignup (e, userData) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSignup(userData)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <main className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.formSide}>
          <h1>SIGNUP</h1>

          <Input
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
            autofocus={true}
          />
          <Input
            id="email"
            label="E-mail"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

Signup.propTypes = {
  onSignup: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Signup
```

My component Input has this code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import MaskedInput from 'react-maskedinput'
import styles from './styles.scss'

function Input (props) {
  let iconComp

  if (props.icon) {
    iconComp = (<img src={props.icon} alt="Icon" />)
  }

  let input = ''

  if (props.type === 'date') {
    input = (
      <MaskedInput
        ref={inp => inp && props.autofocus && inp.focus()}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        mask="11/11/1111"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        className={styles.input}
      />
    )
  } else {
    input = (
      <input
        ref={inp => inp && props.autofocus && inp.focus()}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        id={props.id}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        type={props.type}
        className={styles.input}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <label htmlFor={props.id} className={styles.label}>{props.label}</label>
      <br />
      {input}
      {props.error &&
        <span className={styles.error}>
          {props.errorMessage}
        </span>
      }
      {iconComp}
    </div>
  )
}

Input.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  icon: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  autofocus: PropTypes.bool,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string
}

Input.defaultProps = {
  icon: '',
  placeholder: '',
  type: 'text',
  autofocus: false,
  error: false,
  errorMessage: ''
}

export default Input
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you put it in a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: if you make a demo I think I have a solution but I can't test it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmKQqy

Comment: thanks, i got a simple solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so a simple solution is to enhance your SignUp component to have another property called nameAutoFocus and initialize it to true. Use this property to set the autofocus boolean value. Then add the method componentDidMount and inside set nameAutoFocus to false.

```
    class Signup extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          name: '',
          email: '',
        }

        this.nameAutoFocus = true; //new
      }

      onSignup (e, userData) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.onSignup(userData)
      }

       //new
      componentDidMount() {
        this.nameAutoFocus = false;
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <main>
            <div>
              <h1>SIGNUP</h1>

              <Input
                id="name"
                label="Name"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
                autofocus={this.nameAutoFocus}
              />
              <Input
                id="email"
                label="E-mail"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
          </main>
        )
      }
    }
```

This works because the initial value of nameAutoFocus is passed to the input giving it focus then componentDidMount will run setting it to false so the next time state changes it won't set the autofocus property to true. This essentially is giving it focus only once when initially rendered.

codepen: http://codepen.io/floor_/pen/PmNRKV?editors=0011
don't forget to click run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each time you render Input, new line arrow function gets created for `ref` and called. So it execute `inp.focus()` each time. One way to avoid this is using class component and define `ref` callback method as a class function.

```
class Input extends React.Component {

  refCallback(inp){
    if(this.props.autofocus) inp.focus();
  }

  render(){
    let input = ''

    if (this.props.type === 'date') {
      input = (
        <MaskedInput
          ref={this.refCallback}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          mask="11/11/1111"
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      )
    } else {
      input = (
        <input
          ref={this.refCallback}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          id={this.props.id}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          type={this.props.type}
        />
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
        <br />
        {input}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Input
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmqxWy

*(My previous code had some issues since I couldn't test it. But now I have updated the code and it works)*

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, but it worked! I'll make a demo, @floor

Comment: My previous code had some issues since I couldn't test it. But now I have updated the code and it works. Also I included the updated codepen.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara this solution doesn't work for me, nor does it work in the codepen.

Comment: @floor I'm surprised. This nicely works for me. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzmd_IKe3Y-oNHFBYUxWM1FkdGs/view?usp=sharing
Let's see what leonero has to say.

Comment: This solution worked for me :D but @floor's solution is a bit simpler.